# What to do when a question has an answer in another SE?

Tags: discussion

What to do when a question has an answer in another SE?

E.g. the question [Should I find a processor with "hyper-threading?"](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50/40):

> The Intel Core i7 processor has a feature known as "hyper-threading."
>   Quoting their [website](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/hyper-threading/hyper-threading-technology.html):
>
> > Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology (Intel® HT Technology)1 uses processor resources more efficiently, enabling multiple threads to run
> >     on each core. As a performance feature, it also increases processor
> >     throughput, improving overall performance on threaded software.
>
> Of course, this sounds a bit like an advertisement, and it doesn't
>   show whether it has any less desirable qualities to it, such as
>   increased power usage.
>
> What exactly is hyper-threading? When should I buy a processor that
>   utilizes this?

is pretty much answered on https://superuser.com/q/122536/116475.

Options:

- the question should be closed
- leave an answer with a link pointing to the other SE
- leave an answer with a link pointing to the other SE + copy paste some fragments of it
- leave an answer with a link pointing to the other SE + copy paste all useful information

Leaving a comment is not an option as comments on regarded as temporary on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the question should be closed

No. The existence of a similar question on another Stack Exchange site has no bearing on the suitability of the question on this site.

> leave an answer with a link pointing to the other SE

No. This is a question and answers site, not a link collection. A link does not make an answer.

> leave an answer with a link pointing to the other SE + copy paste some fragments of it

Ok, as long as all the relevant fragments are copied. Do include proper attribution (quote formatting and a link to the author's profile).

> leave an answer with a link pointing to the other SE + copy paste all useful information

Ok, as long as only the relevant fragments are copied. Do include proper attribution (quote formatting and a link to the author's profile).

---

What really *should* be done is to **answer the question in the way that's most relevant for *this* site**. If the answers on the other site are interesting, then by all means do cite them. But we're here to make the best answers for *this* site.

(Where [Should I find a processor with "hyper-threading?"](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50) is answered is really Wikipedia. It isn't a good example.)

Answer (score 2):

We're in a closed beta, and we should, in an ideal world, we should be striving to make questions, and especially answers, of the highest quality. Linking to other SE sites is fine, especially if we quote them, but make content of our own as well.

Comment: What's the point of writing own content when a high-quality answer has been written somewhere else?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Which is why I say that we should quote them. Regardless, in addition to Enderland's answer, you didn't even answer the second part of the question anyway.

Comment: Ok for quoting. Didn't I since the second part of the question with "It is useful if you plan to have more threads running than the number of physical cores, which is likely to be the case, but the performance gains won't be miraculous though."?

Answer (score 0):

> When should I buy a processor that utilizes this?

I disagree that the existing answer addresses this. It's a list of technical specs, at best. The question is more, "when purchasing hardware how should I evaluate this?"

I have written my own answer to address the points missing in the answer you linked: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/57/6

Comment: The question asks specifically "What exactly is hyper-threading? When should I buy a processor that utilizes this?". The existing answer precisely explains what hyper-threading is. Then I wrapped up saying when buyers should care.